# Implement button dragging with momentum?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've managed to implement a draggable button in Objective-C for an iPhone app using the code shown at this link:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/11/draggable-buttons-labels/

I was wondering if a library exists which would implement the dragging with momentum?
So if the user moved the button and then let go, it would continue to move for a little while, depending on a drag coefficient.

I searched for a library, googled "ios button with momentum" but came up empty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you have to support iOS 6**

You can animate change to the button's `center` when pan gesture ends:

```
if(panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatedEnded)
{
    finalVelocty.x = velocity.x;
    finalyVelocity.y = velocity.y;
    NSTimeInterval animationTime = 0.25; //adjust the time to your needs
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
      button.center = ... // calculate button's 'final' center (depending on velocity?)
    } completion:nil]; 
}
```

**For iOS 7 or newer**

Apple's introduced UIKit Dynamics framework (consisting of [UIDynamicAnimator](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/index.html) and UIDynamicItemBehavior subclasses) in iOS 7. It's a physics engine integrated into UIKit. You can use it to achieve the "momentum" effect.

An example which you may find useful: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/introduction-to-uimotioneffect/

Comment: Thanks for this, I was going to look it up but I've been informed we have to support iOS 6 :(...

Comment: According to Apple 95% of devices are on iOS 7 or newer: https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/. I'd  recommend to not support iOS6. It dramatically limits your possibilities and requires much effort for little in return.

Comment: Thanks for the info Michal, unfortunately management wouldn't budge :S

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this for my purpose in the end using the pan gesture recognizer.
In the gesture recogniser method, I get the final velocity.

```
if(timeDiff > 0.2)
{
    velocity.x = velocity.y = 0;
}

if(panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatedEnded)
{
    finalVelocity.x = velocity.x;
    finalVelocity.y = velocity.y;

    // Start a timer and implement the object movement in the timer callback
}
```

If anyone knows of a better way, please let me know :)

Comment: It may be better to use one of the `[UIView animateWithDuration...]` methods instead of a timer, it should look better and feel more 'natural' to the user.

Comment: I've added it to my original answer